# why does while (cout << A[--N] << ' ' && N) and while (cout << A[--N] << ' ') gave me two different answer, what does N here do?

Tags: c++

The code is like the following

```
int main() {

 int N, i = 0;

cin >> N;

int *A = new int[N];

while (cin >> A[i++])
    ;

while (cout << A[--N] << ' ' && N)
    ;

delete[] A;

return 0;
}
```

when I delete the &&N, I got many zero in output, I really don't know why

Comment: What do you expect will ever eventually make the second `while` loop end without the `&& N`?

Comment: @joseph run out of couts obs.

Comment: What do you think happens when you don't have *exactly* `N` integer values in your input?

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
std::cout << A[--N] << ' '
```

returns true if the there were no errors. The loop

```
while (std::cout << A[--N] << ' ');
```

outputs values until an error occurs. As long as `A[--N]` does not try to read unaccessible memory,

```
 std::cout << A[--N] << ' '
```

will evaluate to `true`.

The program

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a[5];
    std::cout << a[-10];
    return 0;
}
```

has undefined behavior, but it can be compiled and executed. In many cases it will output some nonsense but the return value of

```
std::cout << a[-10];
```

will be `true`.

The `&& N` in your question stops the loop when `N` reaches `0`.